# Cannot access value from case class

Tags: json, scala, class, http

I am trying to use the sttp core library along with the sttp json4s library in order to receive a json response and convert it to a case class.

The source code on Github is **[here](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/scalaexercises)** and the documentation for this example that I am trying to replicate is **[here](http://sttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#get-and-parse-json-using-the-akka-http-backend-and-json4s)**

The response to the `GET` request to the URL `http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar` looks like:

```
{
  "args": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Cookie": "_gauges_unique_day=1; _gauges_unique_month=1; _gauges_unique_year=1; _gauges_unique=1; stale_after=never", 
    "Forwarded": "for=49.255.235.138", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Save-Data": "on", 
    "Scheme": "http", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "origin": "49.255.235.138, 66.249.82.79", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar"
}
```

The case class which attempts to read the json response above looks like:

```
case class HttpBinResponse(
  args: Map[String, String],
  origin: String,
  headers: Map[String,String]
)
```

> The case class has been defined at the top of the test file and is accessible to the test.

This test passes:

```
it should "send a GET request parse response as JSON" in {
  implicit val backend = HttpURLConnectionBackend()
  val queryParams = Map("foo" -> "bar", "bugs" -> "life")

  val endpoint:Uri = uri"http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar"

  val request = sttp
    .get(endpoint)
    .response(asJson[HttpBinResponse])

  val response = request.send()
  // response.body is an Either

  response.code should be(200)
  val res = response.body.fold(_ => { "Error" }, a => { a })

  res shouldBe a[HttpBinResponse]
}
```

The code that produces the error looks like this:

```
it should "send a GET request parse response as JSON" in {
  implicit val backend = HttpURLConnectionBackend()

  val queryParams = Map("foo" -> "bar", "bugs" -> "life")

  val endpoint:Uri = uri"http://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar"

  val request = sttp
    .get(endpoint)
    .response(asJson[HttpBinResponse])

  val response = request.send()
  // response.body is an Either

  response.code should be(200)
  val res = response.body.fold(_ => { "Error" }, a => { a })

  res shouldBe a[HttpBinResponse]
  println(res.origin)
}
```

However, when I try and access a value from the `res.origin`, I see the error that is `value origin is not a member of java.io.Serializable`

```
28. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/localuser/Do/scalaexercises/target/scala-2.12/test-classes...
[error] /Users/localuser/Do/scalaexercises/src/test/scala/example/SttpSpec.scala:58: value origin is not a member of java.io.Serializable
[error]     println(res.origin)
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Comment: It might really be extremely helpful, if you posted the code, that produces the error (the term `origin` is found nowhere else aside from you class definition and the error message).

Comment: @Dima tell me if this is better, I have included the json response and the case class at the top, the case class is defined at the top of the test file.

Comment: what type is `val res`?

Comment: the test says that it is of type `[HttpBinResponse]` because `response` is of type `Response[HttpBinResponse]`. I am just trying to follow the docs defined **[here](http://sttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html)**. I dont understand why the error refers to `java.io.serializable`

Comment: It is `Serializable` because left side of `fold` returns a `String`, and `Serializable` is the only common supertype of `String` and `HttpBinResponse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by Rob Norris [on the gitter scala channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) as:

> When you fold the Either the result is Serializable. Try pattern matching on it, or fold to sys.error instead of String.

1. Pattern Matching on the result:

   ```
   val res = response.body.fold(_ => { "Error" }, a => { a })
   res match {
     case HttpBinResponse(_, origin) => {
       println("-----------------------------")
       print("The origin for the request is ")
       print(origin)
       println("-----------------------------")
     }
     case _ => "Error"
   }
   ```
2. fold the Left to `sys.error` instead of String, no pattern matching needed in this case:

   ```
   val res = response.body.fold(
     _ => { error("Error") },
     a => { a }
   )
   println(res.origin)
   res.args should contain("foo" -> "bar")
   res.args should contain key("bugs")
   res.args should contain value("life")
   res.origin.length should be >10
   ```

Either of these two approaches would solve the issue.